# Moving Vertices Creates new faces?

Tags: modeling, vertices, transforms, extrude

I'm trying to make stem shapes for a plant, and merged a cube into a single vertice. I started extruding multiple vertices for the stem, however, when I try to adjust a specific vertice using the 'g' key, instead of moving, it creates a new vertice and a face in between. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely accidentally created duplicate geometry and now when you move it it appears to be creating new geometry but it was really already there. In Edit mode simply select all vertices and the Merge By Distance to automatically remove the duplicate vertices and faces.